# Postman health check script to except specific 500 respsonse

Tags: postman

Hi im looking to update my current script which checks health on some items, out of the list one of them is down and will respond with a 503 (expected!), however i want to get postman to return a OK status if the stats is 503, can someone please help with what i need to insert into the following script:

```
{
pm.test("Status code is 200", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});

pm.test("Status is ok", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.status).to.eql("OK");
});
```

This is the response: - 503

```
{
    "environment": "uk-retail-production:production",
    "proxy": "uk-apigee-rds:34 (build 130)",
    "status": "DOWN",
    "targetEnv": "",
    "services": {
        "abc": {
            "status": "200"
        },
        "hyp": {
            "status": "200"
        },
        "stats": {
            "status": "503"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you running through the list in Postman? A CSV data file, a setNextRequest loop or some other method? Ideally the list needs to include the expected status code that you can store in a variable and use in the assertion instead of the hardcoded 200 or 503.  You can use backticks and string literals to customize the test case name with the aforementioned status code variable.

Comment: I am confusing you want to detect 503 error in `Tests` of Postman? It means. If got that response JSON string (second code in your question), raise an error condition at Tests tab?

Comment: Thanks so we are checking consul for the status and we want to acept thee 503 for stats only